# Максимально редактируемый шаблон WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Делаю шаблон на WordPress, который состоит всего из одной страницы (лендинг). Сложность в том, что нужна возможность из панели администратора изменять текст и изображения во всех блоках, где это требуется (их больше 10).
Как это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вполне должен помочь плагин [Advanced Custom Fields](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). Добавляете группу полей к посту, это могут быть тексты, изображения(как id, так и адреса), цвета и прочие мета-данные. Все эти поля можно потом вытянуть на страницу(в адрес изображения, цвет фона и т.д.) с помощью функции `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'имя_поля', true) ?>`. Сам использовал только для получения текстовых данных, но проблем с цветами и id картинок из библиотеки возникнуть не должно. Удачи.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться функцией get_post() чтобы получить отдельную запись по ID или get_page() (страницу) в нужное место шаблона.